# How to copy the format from a cell with the same value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a schedule table with weekdays in the top row and assignments in the left column.

In each cell in the table I can choose who has the assignment from a drop down list created using data validation. For each week day there is a list of the available persons on that given day under the table.

Each person has their own format, and right now I have a conditional formatting rule for each person. For instance, the first rule formats all cells that contain the text "AAA" with AAA's format. The next rule formats all cells that contain the text "BBB" with BBB's format etc.

I would like to know if instead it is possible to format the lists under the table and then have the format copied to each cell in the table that contains the same text. Will I need to use VBA to do this, or is it possible with e.g. conditional formatting?

Comment: Sounds like you'd need VBA.

Comment: I would set up your list of people as a Table (ListObject) to make adding/deleting people easier, then use a Find call limited to that Table to find the cell that matches.  Once you have that, it's a simple Copy/PasteSpecial Formats call.

Comment: Let me change that comment: Instead of using Copy/PasteSpecial Formats, just set the properties of your target cell to those of the source cell.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the range with your schedule is named "Schedule" and that your list of people is in a Table named tblPeople with the people in the first column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngFound As Range
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("Schedule")) Is Nothing Then 'Check if the cell being changed is in your "Schedule" range
        Set rngFound = Sheets(1).ListObjects("tblPeople").ListColumns(1).Range.Find(What:=Target.Value) 'Find your source cell
        Target.Interior.Color = rngFound.Interior.Color 'Set your target cell formats to the same formats in the source cell - add any additionaql formats as needed
    End If
End Sub
```